# Debug .Net Framework 4.6 Angular Web project couldn't set breakpoint in angular typescript code

Tags: c#, angular, visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2017

I am working on this web project, it is a C# Web project in .Net Framework 4.6 with Angular 6 as the web front end. So, in short, the project entry point is Program.cs -> Startup.cs, where a bunch of services get added into the project through dependency injection. Then the front end angular code will launch to display in the browser. I am currently using visual studio 2017 to run this whole code base and it works well, except that I couldn't set breakpoint inside any of the typescript files as I saw in many tutorials out there, it simply says that breakpoints can't be set. I suppose the running thread is in C# and angular is in a separate thread?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/debug-nodejs?view=vs-2017#debug-client-side-script might be useful

Comment: @ADyson that link looks really promising, I will give it a thorough read through